# Out of bounds exception while using an array of another class in another class

Tags: android, arrays, static, indexoutofboundsexception

I have added an Activity for a quiz in my app. I use the integer array `selected_options` to store the options selected by the user. The quiz shows the user 5 questions per try and stores it in the array, then I have added a Solutions Activity where in the options selected by the user are shown in red color if the answer is wrong and green otherwise. I have no problem in showing the green color as I directly call the answer from the database and highlight accordingly.

But I am facing a problem while highlighting the wrong options selected by the user as the `selected_options` array is not working as I want it to. Also, I get a `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=4; index=4` error when I reach the bottom of the ScrollView in the solutions Activity and the activity crashes.

Here is how i declare the variable `selected_options`:

```
    public static final ArrayList<questionObject> selected_questions = new ArrayList<>();
    public static int[] selected_options;
    public ArrayList<questionObject> result;
    public ArrayList<questionObject> seen_questions;
    TextView question, option1_text, option2_text, option3_text, option4_text, qCount;
    ConstraintLayout[] options = new ConstraintLayout[4];
    DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    String currentUserID;
    private Dialog loadingDialog;
    
    private int quesNum;
    private int score;
```

Here's how I initialize it in the `onCreate()` function:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setStatusBarGradiant(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.quiz_activity);

        seen_questions = new ArrayList<>();
        result = new ArrayList<>();
        selected_options = new int[5];


        question = findViewById(R.id.question_text);
        qCount = findViewById(R.id.quest_num);
```

This is how I add the selected options in the `onClick()` method:

```
public void onClick(View view) {

        int selectedOption = 0;

        switch (view.getId()) {

            case R.id.option_1_tile:
                selectedOption = 1;
                break;
            case R.id.option_2_tile:
                selectedOption = 2;
                break;
            case R.id.option_3_tile:
                selectedOption = 3;
                break;
            case R.id.option_4_tile:
                selectedOption = 4;
                break;

            default:

        }

        selected_options[quesNum] = selectedOption;
        checkAnswer(selectedOption, view);
    }
```

And this is how I try to use it in the `quizAdater`:

```
class questionAdapter extends BaseAdapter {


    TextView question, option1_text, option2_text, option3_text, option4_text, explanation, source;
    ConstraintLayout[] options = new ConstraintLayout[4];
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<questionObject> questions = quizActivity.selected_questions;
    private int[] optionsSelected = quizActivity.selected_options;

    public questionAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<questionObject> arrayList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.questions = arrayList;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return questions.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.quiz_solutions_row, parent, false);
        question = convertView.findViewById(R.id.question_text);
        option1_text = convertView.findViewById(R.id.option_1_text);
        option2_text = convertView.findViewById(R.id.option_2_text);
        option3_text = convertView.findViewById(R.id.option_3_text);
        option4_text = convertView.findViewById(R.id.option_4_text);
        explanation = convertView.findViewById(R.id.explanation);

        source = convertView.findViewById(R.id.source_button);


        options[0] = convertView.findViewById(R.id.option_1_tile);
        options[1] = convertView.findViewById(R.id.option_2_tile);
        options[2] = convertView.findViewById(R.id.option_3_tile);
        options[3] = convertView.findViewById(R.id.option_4_tile);

        question.setText(questions.get(position).getQuestion());
        option1_text.setText(questions.get(position).getOption1());
        option2_text.setText(questions.get(position).getOption2());
        option3_text.setText(questions.get(position).getOption3());
        option4_text.setText(questions.get(position).getOption4());
        explanation.setText("Explanation: " + questions.get(position).getExplanation());

        source.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(context, urlActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("url", questions.get(position).getSource());
                i.putExtra("name", "Information Source");
                context.startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        if (optionsSelected[position] != questions.get(position).getAnswer()) {

            options[position].setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.RED));
        }

        switch (questions.get(position).getAnswer()) {
            case 1:
                options[0].setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.GREEN));
                break;
            case 2:
                options[1].setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.GREEN));
                break;
            case 3:
                options[2].setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.GREEN));
                break;
            case 4:
                options[3].setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.GREEN));
                break;

        }

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Here's the dummy code as requested by a user:

1. declare the integer array variable `selected_options` in the quizActivity class
2. Initialize the integer array in the `onCreate()` method as `selected_options = new int[5];`
3. Add the option selected by the user(5 questions are shown to the user and each has 4 options) as 1-for option A, 2-for option 2 and so on
4. In the `quizAdapter` class, initiate an integer array `optionsSelected` and store the values of the variable array `selected_options` from the quizActivity Class in it using `private int[] optionsSelected = quizActivity.selected_options;`
5. If the user had selected a wrong option, display the option he selected in red color in the solutions Activity using

   if (optionsSelected[position] != questions.get(position).getAnswer()) {

   ```
            options[position].setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.RED));
        }
   ```

I have checked the logs and the variable `quesNum` correctly goes from 0 to 4 and the `selected_options` array is also working as expected so I am not able to debug what might be causing the problem

Comment: `selected_options = new int[4];`

Comment: is the rest of the implementation correct for my use case? And why `int[4]`?

Comment: I have 5 questions per try so shouldn't it be `[5]`? And doing that crashes the quiz on the last question itself

Comment: `doing that crashes the quiz on the last question itself` which line? did you debug?

Comment: `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=4; index=4
        at inspire2connect.inspire2connect.quiz.quizActivity.onClick(quizActivity.java:345)` on the line `selected_options[quesNum] = selectedOption;` in the `onClick()` method which I have given above

Comment: I have tried to make the question as clear as I could, however if you need any more clarifications/code please tell me to do so. Any input will be really helpful, thanks!

Comment: okay.is there any problem if you create dummy cod for it?

Comment: I have added it. I haven't written many dummy codes but have tried my best, please have a look at it

Comment: https://github.com/tavlab-iiitd/WashKaro this is the link for the entire project if you want to take a look at it. You can find the code for the quiz in the quiz folder.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222298/discussion-between-ravish-jha-and-intellij-amiya).

Comment: google-services.json is missing

Comment: you can download it here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SIjmZ6ChC-9JrZd1tds64wP7iXejSU6J/view?usp=sharing  then move it to your app folder

Comment: Okay. I will check it tomorrow morning

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222359/discussion-between-ravish-jha-and-intellij-amiya).

Comment: Did you check it?

Answer (score 0):

Add a check before setting selectedOption to list as below -

```
if(quesNum < 4){
    selected_options[quesNum] = selectedOption;
    checkAnswer(selectedOption, view);
}
```

Check when and where you are increasing the value of quesNum. Try to print its value before getting index from list. It is 4 that is why crash is there because index value is greater than list size.

Comment: shouldn't it be `(quesNum < 5)` because i have 5 questions in total to show?

Comment: As per your crash logs, it is crashing for index 4. That is why i asked to print value for quesNum. You will come to know the exact value and issue.

Comment: it is logging as 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 only. What might be the problem then?

Comment: Now check try to print the selected_options list size. If list size prints 5 then we need to debug the code. But if the list size will print 4 then the crash is obvious.

Comment: `2020-09-30 15:27:23.281 32701-32701/inspire2connect.inspire2connect D/Size: Value: 5
2020-09-30 15:27:44.652 32701-32701/inspire2connect.inspire2connect D/Size: Value: 5
2020-09-30 15:27:48.467 32701-32701/inspire2connect.inspire2connect D/Size: Value: 5
2020-09-30 15:27:52.678 32701-32701/inspire2connect.inspire2connect D/Size: Value: 5
2020-09-30 15:27:55.101 32701-32701/inspire2connect.inspire2connect D/Size: Value: 5`

Comment: I added the line `Log.d("Size", "Value: " + selected_options.length);
        checkAnswer(selectedOption, view);` in the end of the `onClick()` method and got this output

Comment: Try to check with the same condition you was getting the crash before. I hope after adding the if condition the crash is not there for you now. Share the values for the list and the variable that you are keeping for the quiz number tracking. I mean for this  - 'But I am facing a problem while highlighting the wrong options selected by the user as the selected_options array is not working as I want it to. Also, I get a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=4; index=4 error when I reach the bottom of the ScrollView in the solutions Activity and the activity crashes.'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222297/discussion-between-priyanka-rajput-and-ravish-jha).

Comment: `2020-09-30 15:32:14.060 4484-4484/inspire2connect.inspire2connect D/Size: Value: [4, 0, 0, 0, 0]
2020-09-30 15:32:16.674 4484-4484/inspire2connect.inspire2connect D/Size: Value: [4, 1, 0, 0, 0]
2020-09-30 15:32:19.712 4484-4484/inspire2connect.inspire2connect D/Size: Value: [4, 1, 2, 0, 0]
2020-09-30 15:32:23.993 4484-4484/inspire2connect.inspire2connect D/Size: Value: [4, 1, 2, 1, 0]
2020-09-30 15:32:27.054 4484-4484/inspire2connect.inspire2connect D/Size: Value: [4, 1, 2, 1, 1]` the values are getting stored as expected, so there isn't any problem with the selected_options array imo

Comment: I will add your if condition and check again